# How to create a drop down lookup field in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

new to PHP here,

I have a library database in MySQL Workbench that has tables: Student, Book, and Checkin. I am trying to use HTML and PHP to display it on a webpage and so far it has been going fine till trying to display s_id in the checkin table as "s_name" which is student name and the same for b_id to b_name. I have created the foreign key connections in Workbench but can't figure out how to create a drop down option that shows the Student Names and Book Names that I have already made in their respective tables (instead of s_id and b_id).

Lookup fields are super easy in MS Access but creating a PHP version has proven to be difficult as a beginner...Here is what it looks like right now.

[image: This is what it looks like:]

```
        <?php
                include('conn.php');
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `checkin`");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['c_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['s_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['b_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['c_date']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['c_in']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="edit_checkin.php?id=<?php echo $row['c_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                            <a href="delete_checkin.php?id=<?php echo $row['c_id']; ?>">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any helps or tips are much appreciated!

Comment: You should post the code of your application, as well as any attempts you have made with specific questions.

Comment: Sure thing, I have updated my post

Comment: i don't see any dropdown in your code

Comment: Thats because I do not know how to write it incorporating what I have and with a lookup field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, now with prepared query:

## lib4.php

```
<form action='add_borrowing1.php' method='post'>
          <br>
          <select name="student">
        <?php
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "library");
          $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT studentId, studentName
          FROM students";
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
          print "<option value='students' selected>Students</option>";
          While ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            print "<option value=" . $row["studentId"] . ">"
          . $row["studentName"] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
          </select>
                    <p>Book:</p>
          <br>
          <select name="book">
        <?php
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "library");
          $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT bookId, bookName
          FROM books";
          $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
          print "<option value='books' selected>Books</option>";
          While ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            print "<option value=" . $row["bookId"] . ">"
          . $row["bookName"] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" />
          </form>

          <?php
          if (!isset($_GET["raw"])) {
            echo "";
          }
          else {
            echo "Borrowing has been successfully added!";
          }

?>

add_borrowing.php
======================
<?php
$book = $_POST["book"];
$student = $_POST["student"];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "library");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO borrowing (bookId, studentId) VALUES (?,?)";


$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);

            /*
            Explanation:
            i Integers
            d Doubles
            b Blobs
            s Everything Else 
            */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $book,
                                   $student);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                mysqli_close($link);

header("Location:lib4.php?raw=1");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why you added an additional table called 'borrowing'? Is this supposed to be a form of my 'checkin' table?

Comment: Can be. I just have helped here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280355/can-not-assign-a-book-to-a-user/50310671#50310671 and the same script send you. Take what you need from my script. In my script is answer for you.